# CSS class unexpectedly removed on any click event

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very strange issue going on with a site I'm building for a client. I have a series of CSS animations on an `SVG` element which are triggered by a `hover` event on a parent element... here's a quick peek at the SASS:

```SCSS
.top-bar {
    .name {
        a {
            display: block;

            svg {
                max-height: $topbar-height;
                padding-top: rem-calc(10);
                padding-bottom: rem-calc(10);

            }

            @media #{$large-up} {
                width: 150px;
            }
        }
        &.hover {

            svg {
                > path {
                    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                            animation-duration: 1s;
                    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
                            animation-fill-mode: both;
                    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
                            animation-name: fadeInUp;

                    &:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 0.2s; }
                    &:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 0.3s; }
                    &:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 0.4s; }
                    &:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 0.5s; }
                    &:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 0.6s; }
                }

                > g {
                    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                            animation-duration: 1s;
                    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
                            animation-fill-mode: both;
                    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
                            animation-name: fadeInRight;
                            animation-delay: 0.6s;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

As the animation will take a few seconds to complete and I don't want it to stop  if the user removes their mouse from hovering on the parent element, I have a little bit of jQuery which is adding a `.hover` class and the animations are tied to to that. Here is my JS:

```JS
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.top-bar .name').hover(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        animateHover(this);
    }, function() {
        animateHover(this);
    });


    function animateHover(elm) {
        var $elm = $(elm),
            hover_class = 'hover',
            status = $elm.hasClass(hover_class);

        if ( !status ) {
            $elm.addClass(hover_class);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $elm.removeClass(hover_class);
            }, 2500 );
        } else { return false; }
    }

});
```

The script works fine, a class is added on hover and after 2.5s it's removed... perfect. Except if the user clicks *anywhere* on the page the class is mysteriously removed! This makes the animation stop and the whole SVG just looks broken.

I don't have any JS that is conflicting or is even tied to the `click` event, so I'm rather baffled as to what is causing the browser to remove the `.hover` class.

Any suggestions on what may be causing this!?

Comment: Can you make a reduced test environment at jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: You can see it via the pre-production server: http://harlex.tutchhq.co.uk/ Just hover over the logo in the top left.